# Break and rerun while loop c++ Windows

Tags: c++, while-loop, break

I'm a rookie programmer, so please be polite.

Well i'm trying to write a simple Terminal Backgammon game, just for fun, but i have a problem.

The entire game runs in a while loop which keeps re running as long as nobody moved all their bricks to the end of the board. 
A simple integer controls whatever it is black or white who plays.

I wrote a function to check for any possible moves, cause i want to program to skip the turn in case absolutely no moves can be made.

Well, i want this function to run and in case it returns false(No possible moves) then i want the rest of the code to skip and change the turn to the next player. For example if the dice combination gives no possible moves for black, then i want the program to skip black and go to white.

So i sort of want to break the rest of the while loop, but keep it running.

It's a little complicated for me to explain the issue, but i hope you guys understand.

Thanks alot
- Martin

Comment: Could you post some code samples?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to use `continue`:

```
while (someCondition)
{
  doSomething();

  if (someOtherCondition)
    continue;

  doSomethingElse();
}
```

In this example, if `someOtherCondition` is true, the `continue` statement will cause the program to jump back to the top of the loop rather than continuing to execute the following statements.  If `someOtherCondition` is false, `doSomethingElse()` will get run as normal.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is roughly what you want to know.
Hope it helps.

```
while( keepRunning )
{
    bool noPossibleMoves = checkForPossibleMoves();

    setup for each loop iteration
    Do things here that are always necessary.
    if( noPossibleMoves )
    {
        continue;  // This will go to the top of the while loop
    }
    wait for user input etc...
    ... 
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot too, very help full!